# ArrayReference<T> Windows Phone 8 sample

Tags: windows-phone-8, c++-cx

Can anyone point me toward an example of using `Platform::ArrayReference<T>` on the Windows Phone 8?  Every attempt I have made has caused a compiler syntax error.  It is [listed in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj127099.aspx) as a part of WinRT, but I can't find anything that conclusively identifies this as desktop-only or not.

I want to use this in my phone app to decrease the number of copies that are going on as I shuffle data between C# and C++, but if this is not allowed, perhaps I'll just have to live with those copies.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Every attempt I have made has caused a compiler syntax error."  Can you show your attempts and the resulting compilation errors?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Thank you for your response, but I realized I was using the class incorrectly.  I was trying to use it as an input parameter so that when a C# class passed my class a float[] I would avoid an extra copy, but now I realize this class is meant to be created on the C++ side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I have been thinking about `ArrayReference` wrong.  When interfacing with C# code, you still need to use `Array` as your input parameters, but when passing `Arrays` to other C++ objects or to C# code from C++ code, you can use `ArrayReference` to wrap a C array in a Platform wrapper.